# Box.com api - If we change tags for a file... does the modified_at or content_modified_at change too?

Tags: box-api, box

In Box.com they have "tags" for a file object

I'm wondering if the `file.info.modified_at` or `file.info.content_modified_at` will be updated along with the tags?

Looks like not when I tried it... i updated tags and those dates did not change.

How then do I know if the tags field has been updated so I can act accordingly? I would have to diff the Tag fields of old and new and that would cause extra network usage not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box.com support emailed me to let me know this is not supported. I created a new feature request.